# hibernate: how to create a composite foreign key in xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a class `Event` containing a composite primary key (start date and end date).

A `EventPlanning` class holds a `Set` of such `Event` objects and has to persist them using hibernate with XML. 
I can do this for classes with a common primary key:

```
<!-- EventPlanning xml -->
....
<id name="id" column="id">
<generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="name" column="name" type="string" update="false" />

<set name="events" table="events" cascade="all">
    <key column="event_id">   // ###### here! ######
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="myPackage.Event" />
</set>
...
```

but I can't find out how this works with a composite key..

replacing the `<key column="event_id">` with the following code doesn't work:

```
<key>
    <property column="start_date" />
    <property column="end_date" />
</key>
```

I'd be glad if somebody can show me the right syntax! :)

the Event xml looks like this:

```
<class name="myPackage.Even" table="events">

        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="startDate" column="start_date" type="date" />
            <key-property name="endDate" column="end_date" type="date" />
        </composite-id>

        <property name="signinDeadline" column="signin_deadline"
            type="date" />
        <property name="confirmationDeadline" column="confirmation_deadline"
            type="date" />

        <set name="participants" table="participants" cascade="all">
            <key column="event_id">
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="myPackage.Participants" />
        </set>

    </class>
```

thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having now worked longer with JPA and Hibernate, I'd just say that you simply should not use composite primary keys. Caches use ids as keys that point to cached values, data retrieving methods like `get` and `load` expect the id as parameter etc. 
The advantages gained by having an id field pay off against the additional space it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me:

```
<class name="YourClass" table="your_table" ...>
  <composite-id name="compositeId" class="DoubleDate">
     <key-property name="start_date" column="start_date"/>
     <key-property name="end_date" column="end_date"/>
  </composite-id>
  ...
 </class>

public class DoubleDate implements Serializable {
   private Date start_date, end_date;
   public DoubleDate() {
   }
   // setters, getters
}

public class YourClass {
   private DoubleDate compositeId;
   // public no args ctr, getters, setters, etc
}
```

Comment: This is quite similar to what my code looks like :) my Event class is like your DoubleDate class, it just has two more fields. I edited the xml part into my post.     The thing I don't get to work is the xml for the "YourClass" ;)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what problem(s) are you getting? Are you getting startup errors, or errors when loading/persisting, etc.?

Comment: In the first code block is this <set>..</set> block where I'd like to persist all the events that are in there. I have to specify the keys there. ATM I do it with an ID I added to my Event class for the moment, but I'd prefer to replace this with the composite key (startDate, endDate) desciribed before! The problem is that I can't find the right syntax to do this. The snipplet postet afterwards causes a red underlining in Eclipse, telling me that this is incorrect syntax. Thanks for your patience so far :)